# Understanding an implicitly defined branch in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Theorem 6.2, chapter 3, of Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis gives conditions for when a function can be written as $e^{g(z)}$. I understand the proof except for the remark that the function g(z) determines a 'branch' of that logarithm.

I understand that changing g(z) by $2\pi i$ won't adjust the value. However, my understanding is that a branch cuts out part of the domain to ensure the log function remains continuous. Yet the definition of g(z) here does not depend on anything being cut out of the domain.

Comment: The same holds in this case since $g(z)=\log(f(z))$ and the $\log$ branch must be specified. In other words, the value depends on the curve $\gamma$.

Comment: but the domain is simply connected, and f(z) is non vanishing, so the value of g(z) is independent of the curve chosen. This seems to make g(z) defined on the entire domain, without a branch being needed. In contrast, defining g(z) = log(f(z)) requires a branch where the value of g(z) 'jumps' across the branch cut, which doesn't happen anywhere here.

Comment: does that make sense? or am I confused in a silly way? thank you also for taking the time to leave a comment :)

Comment: To keep it simple, suppose that $f(z):=z=x+iy$ and the domain is a half plane $x>0$. Then $g(z)=\log(z)$ where we take the principal value of $log$ with the branch cut negative real axis. If the half plane is $x<0$, then the principal value is discontinuous across the negative real axis. We have to choose another branch.

Comment: ah ok thank you. And if the domain was the entire complex plane, what would that mean for the branch cut?

Comment: Let $\,f(z):=\exp(z)\,$ defined for entire complex plane which is nowhere zero. Then $\,g(z)=z+2k\pi i\,$ for some integer $k$ which determines a branch.